# "no commandline connection parameters passed" Knex error

Tags: knex.js

I am attempting to run a knexfile migration using the command

`knex migrate:latest`

and recieve the following error

```
/Users/<MYUSERNAME>/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/knex/bin/utils/cli-config-utils.js:8
    throw new Error(
    ^

Error: No default configuration file '/Users/<MYUSERNAME>/Desktop/Zipline/ed-tester/knexfile.js' found and no commandline connection parameters passed
    at mkConfigObj (/Users/<MYUSERNAME>/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/knex/bin/utils/cli-config-utils.js:8:11)
```

my knexfile.js

```
module.exports = {

  development: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      database: process.env.DB_NAME || 'db',
      user: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
      host: process.env.DB_HOSTNAME,
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    }
  }
};
```

and my .env

```
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_HOSTNAME=localhost
DB_NAME=db
DB_PASSWORD=
DB_SSL=false
```

Can someone please explain what is wrong and how to fix.

Answer (score 2):

try by running following command-
`knex migrate:latest --env development`

Answer (score 2):

You need to add **--knexfile** commandline parameter along with the path to the knexfile.

Example:- `npx knex migrate:latest --knexfile ./db/knexfile.js`

**Note:-** The path to the knexfile will be relative to where you are executing the command from.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. My issue was the following:

I have a knexfile.js looking like this:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const { DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, APP_ENV } = process.env;
module.exports = {

  development: {
    // ...
  },

  staging: {
    // ...
  },

  production: {
    // ...
  },

}[APP_ENV];
```

And I was passing `production-4` as the `APP_ENV` (it doesn't exist in my config). Passing an env that exists (`production`), or adding `production-4` in my list of configs solves the issue.

Make sure knex gets a correct config (with client, connection, pool, migration...)